# irc chat in C programming

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote two programs for a simple IRC chat program in C. This is my first attempt at socket programming. The read program works just fine. The write program technically works but with one minor hitch. It will ping timeout if waiting on fgets to long without input. How do I send PONG if the server sends ping and wait on fgets at the same time. Basically I want to wait for input and read the socket at the same time.

Thank you so much for your help.

Here is the code:

```
/* irc chat program will write to the irc chat server your text */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void error (const char *msg);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* Declare variables for the socket, port number and socket value */

int sockfd, portno, n;

/* Declare the socket server address structure */

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

/* Declare server host structure */

struct hostent *server;

/* Declare a variable for the text to be read from the server */

char buffer[256];

/* Declare a character pointer to send a message */
/* to the server if they ping us */

char *send_message;

/* prints error message if the input is invaild */

if (argc < 3)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
  exit(0);
}

/* converts string to integer and stores the port number */

portno = atoi(argv[2]);

/* open the socket */

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* prints error message if socket can't be opened */

if (sockfd < 0)
   error("ERROR opening socket");
else
   printf("socket opened sucessfully\n");

/* stores server name to connect to */

server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

/* prints error message if host does not exist */

if (server == NULL)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
   exit(0);
}
else
    printf("Found host\n");

/* clears the server address variable of data */

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

/* assigns server address to structure */

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

/* copy server address structure to the server host structure */

bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);

/* Assigns the port number to the port structure */

serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

/* connect to the server */

if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
   error ("ERROR connecting");
else
   printf("connection sucessful\n");

/* send nickname to the server */

n = write(sockfd, "NICK csocket76\r\n", strlen("NICK csocket76\r\n"));

/* send username to the server */

n = write(sockfd, "USER csocket76 8 * :linux\r\n", strlen("USER csocket76 8 * :linux\r\n"));

/* join the channel */

printf("Enter channel to join ex. JOIN #<channel> ");
fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

while (buffer != "*quit")
{  
     bzero(buffer, 256);

     n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);

     /* if the server sends ping we send pong */
     /* and a message to keep our connection alive */

     if (strstr(buffer, "PING :") != NULL) {
       send_message = "PONG :Linux rocks !!";
       write(sockfd, send_message, strlen(send_message));
       printf("%s\n", send_message);
    }

     printf("Type your message ex. PRIVMSG #linux :<message> ");

     /* clear the buffer */

     bzero(buffer,256);

     /* Input data from user */

     fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);

     /* write data to server */

     n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

     /* print error message if it can't write the data */

     if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");

  }

  /* close socket before exiting */

   close(sockfd);

  return 0;
  }

  void error (const char *msg)
  {
     perror(msg);
     exit(0);
  }
```

Comment: I revised while (buffer != "*quit") to while (1)

Comment: Main options are to use [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or threading.

Comment: thank you so much kaylum !! I am going to use select and see how it works out.

Comment: for readability by us humans: Please indent consistently.  Suggest 4 spaces for each level of indent so visible, even with a variable width font.  Suggest: indent after EVERY opening brace: '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, the fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion` )  Amongst other things the functions: `bzero()` and `bcopy()` are not defined.  To acquire the proper definitions, insert the statement: `#include <strings.h>`  (not to be confused with `string.h`)

Comment: the posted code does not compile for several reasons, including the `struct hostent` has no member named `h_addr`.   Also this line: `while (buffer != "*quit")` is comparing addresses when it should be comparing contents.  suggest: `while (strcmp(buffer, "*quit") `

Comment: changing `while (buffer != "*quit")` to `while(1)` will not fix the problems and will result in no method for the user to cleanly exit the program

Comment: regarding this (and the following `if` code block:) `n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));`  the correct check is: `if( n != strlen(buffer) )`  then two possible scenarios need to be addressed. 1) if n>0 then call the write() again with the remainder of the buffer[].  2) if n<0 then call `perror` (and perhaps loop to try the write again or call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code difficult to understand and much more difficult to debug and/or maintain.  The 'magic' numbers are 255 and 256.  Suggest: `#define MAX_BUF_LEN (256)` so the number has a meaningful name, then using that name throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this line: `fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);`  `buffer[] is 256 bytes long.  `fgets()` will properly handle (I.E. not overflow) the buffer. so the second parameter should be similar to: `sizeof(buffer)`

Comment: this line: `write(sockfd, send_message, strlen(send_message));` needs to be modified to check the returned value to determine if an error occurred and handle that error similar to my prior comment about `write()` error handling

Comment: in the `error()` function, a "ERROR" has occurred, so call `exit()` with an error indication, not with a 'all is ok' status.   Suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: If you use the `-Wconversion` parameter, then numerous warnings about 'automatic' type conversions will be raised.  In general, you should fix those warnings.

Comment: the posted code does not compile, so there is nothing to run, so  you did not post the code that has a runtime problem .